# StackOverflow website perforamce

Tags: performance, web

I when i hit stackoveflow website the website comes up with in fraction of seconds ,i know it has to pool latest question and then render all question but how can it can be so fact surely they cant cache it, i would like to know this as i would like to the way they are handling performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sufficient hardware and efficient code. See http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/

Comment: Great! some more info would be great but i think violates Intellectual property rule.